# Safely split contenteditable div by childelement or line in javascript

Tags: javascript, typescript, ecmascript-6

Hi im trying to safely split the contenteditable in 2 div from where the cursor is and will trigger splitHtml function on keypress enter

**Example contenteditable**

**scenario 1**

```
 <span id="editor" contenteditable>
     Welcome something
     <div>sample content <i>here 1</i></div>
     <div>Sample  <b><i><u>content|*here is my cursor*</u></i></b> here 2</div>
     <div>Sample content <b>here 3</b></div>
     <div>Sample content here 4</div>
    </span>
```

**scenario 2**

```
<span id="editor" contenteditable>
 Welcome something|*here is my cursor*
 <div>sample content <i>here 1</i></div>
 <div>Sample  <b><i><u>content</u></i> here 2</div>
 <div>Sample content <b>here 3</b></div>
 <div>Sample content here 4</div>
</span>
```

if i run the code

```
function splitHtml(el){
   //code
   console.log(splitedResult)
}
```

**Expected splitedResult scenario on 1**

```
[
 '<span contenteditable>Welcome something<div>sample content <i>here 1</i></div></span>',
 '<span contenteditable><div>Sample content <b>here 3</b></div><div>Sample content here 4</div></span>'
]
```

**Expected splitedResult on scenario 2**

```
[
 '<span contenteditable><div>sample content <i>here 1</i></div><div>Sample  <b><i><u>content</u></i></b> here 2</div><div>Sample content <b>here 3</b></div><div>Sample content here 4</div></span>'
]
```

Thank you for anyone can help me out

Comment: what action triggers the split? a click? keypress?

Comment: sorry .. action is onenter .. i will edit update the question

Comment: Is the split always one level deep? What should happen if the cursor is inside the `<i>` or `<b>` tags for example?

Comment: @3limin4t0r if cursor is in any tag it always  get the parent element of it even it has nested tag <u><i><b>sample</b></i></u>

Comment: i edited the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is exactly what you want, but you could use something like this:

```js
function nodePath(baseNode, targetNode, currentPath = []) {
  if (baseNode == targetNode) return currentPath;
  currentPath.unshift(targetNode);
  return nodePath(baseNode, targetNode.parentNode, currentPath);
}

document.getElementById("editor").addEventListener("keydown", event => {
  const {currentTarget: editor, code} = event;
  
  if (code != "Enter") return;
  event.preventDefault();
  
  const cursorNode = window.getSelection().anchorNode;
  const [child]    = nodePath(editor, cursorNode);
  const wrappers   = Array.from({length: 2}, () => editor.cloneNode(false));
  
  wrappers.forEach(wrapper => wrapper.removeAttribute("id"));
  
  let seenChild = false;
  for (const node of editor.childNodes) {
    if (!seenChild && node == child) {
      seenChild = true;
    } else if (!seenChild) {
      wrappers[0].append(node.cloneNode(true));
    } else {
      wrappers[1].append(node.cloneNode(true));
    }
  }
  
  console.log("output:");
  wrappers.forEach(wrapper => console.log(wrapper.outerHTML));
});
```

```html
<span id="editor" contenteditable>
  Welcome something
  <div>sample content <i>here 1</i></div>
  <div>Sample  <b><i><u>content</u></i></b> here 2</div>
  <div>Sample content <b>here 3</b></div>
  <div>Sample content here 4</div>
</span>
```

Note that I currently make a copy of your current `#editor` element to create the wrapper, but you could create a new node from scratch pretty easy.

The `nodePath` function traces traces the `targetNode` back to `baseNode`. Take for example `<a><b><c></c></b></a>`. If `<a>` is the `baseNode` and  `<c>` is the `targetNode`. Then `nodePath` will return the array `[<b>, <c>]`.

`cloneNode(false)` will create a shallow clone (clones the node without the child nodes). `cloneNode(true)` will create a deep clone (clones the node and child nodes).

Comment: WOW your answer is mind blowing :D .. I already make my own may to do it. aside from this method .. but think i need to play or use your answer :) thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

```js
let x;
let y;


function handleKeydown(e) {
  if (e.keyCode === 13) {
    e.preventDefault();
    let target = window.getSelection().anchorNode.parentElement;
    if (["I", "B"].some(tag => tag === target.tagName)) target = target.parentElement;
    splitHtml(target);
  }

}


function splitHtml(target) {
  const editable = document.getElementById("editor");
  const innerHTML = editable.innerHTML;
  const split = innerHTML.split(target.outerHTML);
  const output = split.map(ele => "<span contenteditable>" + ele + "</span>");
  //console.log(output)
  document.getElementById("container").innerHTML = output.reduce((t, c) => t + c);
}
```

```html
<div>Input: </div>
<br/>

<span id="editor" contenteditable onkeydown="handleKeydown(event)">
             <span>Welcome</span>
             <div>sample content <i>here 1</i></div>
             <div>Sample content|*here is my cursor* here 2</div>
             <div>Sample content <b>here 3</b></div>
             <div>Sample content here 4</div>
        </span>

   
<br/>
<div>Output:</div>
<br/>

<div id="container">


</div>
```

Comment: @Jake Garbo I think this is it

Comment: Thank you . but on welcome line its not working  and if its has deep level tag it only split the child node not the whole line or parent element